# Find architecture of a .so file (Python)

Tags: python

I would like to find inside python for what architecture a file (in my case .so) has been build.

I known that I can see this in the terminal with the 'file' command.

Example:
`file libstuff.so` gives as output:

```
libstuff.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=3cac824147a873a51c2862fea4e83cfed46c8d9, not stripped
```

I need this in my python script so I don't load the .so file if I running my program on a ARM aarch64 architecture.

I seem to be unable to find anything on this matter...
Is this not possible?

Comment: Could always [read it manually](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format#File_header)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a call to the terminal using the `subprocess` module.

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen([
        'file',
        'libstuff.so'
    ], 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

out, err = proc.communicate()
info = out.decode()
```

Comment: I had also though of this approach but would like to avoid it (if possible)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [pyelftools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyelftools) for identifying the architecture for a shared object file.

Interfacing with shared libraries can be done via [ctypes.cdll](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) in standard library.